# forecasting in time series in R with dplyr and ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, dplyr, time-series, forecasting

Hope all goes well.
I have a data set that I can share a small piece of it:

```
date=c("2022-08-01","2022-08-02","2022-08-03","2022-08-04",
       "2022-08-05","2022-08-6")

sold_items=c(12,18,9,31,19,10)

df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(date),sold_items)
df %>% sample_n(5)
```

```
        date sold_items
1 2022-08-04         31
2 2022-08-03          9
3 2022-08-01         12
4 2022-08-06         10
5 2022-08-02         18
```

I need to forecast the number of **sold items** in the **next two weeks** (14 days after the last available date in the data).
And also need to show the forecasted data along with the current data on one graph using **ggplot**

I have been looking into forecast package to use ARIMA but I am lost and could not convert this data to a **time series object**.
I wonder if someone can provide a solution with dplyr to my problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
# first create df
```

`   df =
tibble(
sold = c(12, 18, 9, 31, 19, 10),
date = seq(as.Date("2022-08-01"),
by = "day",
length = length(sold))) %>%
relocate(date)

```
#then coerce to a tsibble object (requires package fpp3) and model: 

df %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = date) %>% 
  model(ARIMA(sold)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 14)
```